# A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file after DB Shrink

Tags: sql-server

After shrinking an SQL Server database & files, I encountered an error message saying *"A nonrecoverable I/O error occurred on file"* while performing database backup.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

After I did the following steps below, I was able to produce a database backup again.

**Step 1:**

```
use Test_DB

GO
```

**Step 2:**

```
DBCC CheckDB

GO
```

**Step 3:**

1. Right click the Test_DB database then click properties.
2. Choose Option page
3. From Restrict Access option, select Single
4. Click OK and Open Connections dialog will appear. Click Yes if you want to close all connection connected to the database and change the database on single user mode.

-OR-

```
ALTER DATABASE Test_DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT

GO
```

**Step 4:**

```
dbcc checkdb ('Test_DB',repair_rebuild) 

GO
```

**Step 5:**

```
dbcc checkdb ('Test_DB',repair)

GO
```

**Step 6:**

```
ALTER DATABASE Test_DB SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT

GO
```